# Like Button results showing up in "Other" interests

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I have a Wordpress.org based website and I've set it up so that on each individual "post" page (single.php file) there's a Like button above the post so users can Like that individual post.

I was using iFrame and just switched over to XFBML but it didn't fix my problem. My code is:

```
<fb:like send="false" layout="button_count" width="80" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

The problem is when someone clicks "Like" it shows up in their "Other" Like activity on their Facebook page because I guess each post is considered it's own page. How can I make it so each post isn't considered a page and the Like results do not show up in someones "Other" activity?

My website is www.RockItPro.com and for example a single post url is http://www.rockitpro.com/2012/01/04/flyawayhook/

Answer (score 1):

You could use a like button with a fixed url:

```
<fb:like href="http://example.com" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true"></fb:like>
```

That way you likes would end up summed to the page, on the other hand this defeats the purpose of liking those articles for the article as every user on facebook would get redirected to the fixed page.

To fix the Other-Category you will need to categorize your page. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ for examples how to use  so you can tag your ownership of the page and get admin permissions to it's facebook representation.

Comment: Yea I think I figured out the problem. My old opengraph tag was <meta property="og:type" content="blog" /> which caused every single post to be labeled as a "blog". I've changed my opengraph tags in my header.php file to `<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<?php if(is_home()) {
?><meta property="og:title" content="RockItPro.com" /><?php
} else {
?><meta property="og:title" content="<?php the_title_attribute( $args ); ?>" /><?php
}
?>`

Comment: then I scraped my latest post using the lint tool and now it works properly (doesn't show up in Other activity) but when I like an older post that I haven't scraped it still shows up in the "Other" category. Will this work itself out or do I have to scrape every page? lol

Comment: Nah this works itself out after a while. Manually scraping a url will just fore a cache clear on facebooks servers for that url so it speeds things up. But after a while this will update itself for all urls.